# Tinyscrollbar on user control is not working on other pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinyscrollbar

I have a user control that contains a notification icon when I use mouseover event on that icon notification list displayed with a scrollbar like the one of Facebook. I used a custom scrollbar from below link:

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

I added path of .js file which is used in this link to my user control page

I used this user control to master page and many other web pages of my project
but scrollbar is not working

when I added this path of js in each pages then scrollbar it's working but there are many pages I can't give path in.

How should I solve this?

### Edit 1

Tried

```
 <link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/assets/css/website.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/assets/js/homebanner/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js") %>'></script>
```

Comment: please add code or even better link to fiddle with what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

use resolve url to include the file

<%= ResolveUrl("~/fielName.js") %>;

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl(~/styles/MyStyles.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/MyJScript.js")' %>">
```

Add you file in master page.
And use file path as above.

Other wise you will have to give the full path
like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite/scripts/MyJScript.js">
```

Comment: I wrote below in head tag of master page:                                          <link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/assets/css/website.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/assets/js/homebanner/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js") %>'></script>

Answer (score -2):

I solved this using ScriptCombiner.
I saved path of javascript file(~/assets/js/homebanner/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js) in notepad and added to App_Data folder also added JavaScriptMinifier.cs and JavaScriptMinifier.cs to App_Code folder.
Finally I added <%= ScriptCombiner.GetScriptTags("Site_Scripts", 2)%> to my user control page and master page and removed  from user control.